# Static file cache, Angular2 and deployments

Tags: .net, azure, caching

We have an Angular 2 client that runs on .NET Core in Azure under an app service. We recently added the following to the startup.cs:

```
app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
        {
            OnPrepareResponse = ctx =>
            {
                const int durationInSeconds = 86400;
                ctx.Context.Response.Headers[HeaderNames.CacheControl] =
                    "public,max-age=" + durationInSeconds;
            }
        });
```

This caches the static files (including the various bundle.js files) for 1 day. Whilst this gives us performance benefits, we run into problems when deploying new releases. We obviously can't tell each user to try CTRL + F5 but at the same time, we need to cache files for as long as possible.

I haven't been able to find much of a solution in how to handle this.

Is there a common strategy?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, the asp.net core support cache busting.

> Cache busting is the process of appending some form of file version hash to the filename of resources like JavaScript and CSS files. The performance advantage of doing this is that we can tell the browser to cache these files indefinitely without worrying about the client not getting the latest version when the file changes. Since the name of the resource changes when the file contents change, the updated files are always downloaded.
>
> To enabling cache busting, just set the asp-append-version attribute to true.

So I suggest you could add the asp-append-version property in the script tag as below.

```
 <script src="~/js/site.min.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
```

Then it will auto add a hex value behind the js file.

[image]

If you change the js file, it will changed js path to tell the client to get the new js file.

Changed result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that seems the way to go but I can't seem to get it to work. I've added the property like so to a random file: <script src="/assets/lib/sys/jquery.scrollbar.min.js" asp-append-version="true" defer></script> but then when I refresh then go to the file the request URL doesn't show the version. The file is in the wwwroot folder and my startup hyas app.UseStaticFiles(); but still nothing. Any suggestions? We aren't serving any pages from .NET Core, they are all served from the wwwroot folder that Webpack generates.

Comment: As far as I know, if you don't serving any pages from .NET Core, this property will not work. I suggest you could add version number behind the js file. Like this <script src="/assets/lib/sys/jquery.scrollbar.min.js?v=version1" >. It will tell the browser get the new version of the js file. Change the js path will will tell the browser get the new js file.